# How to convert frozendict object into pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following frozendict object:

```
from frozendict import frozendict
my_object = frozendict({'Mn1': 3.9499512091579208, 'Gpsm1': 3.9499512091579208, 'Fam171a1': 3.029245020494556, 'Igfbp5': 6.642908688236191})
```

Then it looks like this:

```
In [95]: my_object
Out[95]: <frozendict {'Mn1': 3.9499512091579208, 'Gpsm1': 3.9499512091579208, 'Fam171a1': 3.029245020494556, 'Igfbp5': 6.642908688236191}>
```

How can I convert that into pandas data frame?

I tried this but failed:

```
In [98]: import pandas as pd

In [99]: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_object)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-68a940d78eca> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_object)

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
    983             raise ValueError('only recognize index or columns for orient')
    984
--> 985         return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
    986
    987     def to_dict(self, orient='dict', into=dict):

~/anaconda2/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    420                                          dtype=values.dtype, copy=False)
    421             else:
--> 422                 raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
    423
    424         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates this? Or at least some code that creates a dummy version of this?

Comment: @coldspeed I updated my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working add parameter `orient='index'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_object, orient='index')
print (df)
                 0
Mn1       3.949951
Gpsm1     3.949951
Fam171a1  3.029245
Igfbp5    6.642909
```

And if necessary also parameter `columns`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_object, orient='index', columns=['col'])
print (df)
               col
Mn1       3.949951
Gpsm1     3.949951
Fam171a1  3.029245
Igfbp5    6.642909
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `orient='index'` to create the DataFrame using dictionary keys as rows:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_object, orient='index')
```